# How to resolve Conversion to Dalvik format failed with error 1 in Android?

Tags: android, format, dalvik

I have written a sample application on using `TabHost`.  I am getting the following error:

> Conversion to Dalvik format failed with error 1

How do I resolve the above issue?

Comment: You need to show your code, or at least your logcat output.  Also see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3284407/conversion-to-dalvik-format-failed-with-error-1-with-javax-net-socketfactory-clas

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, update to the very latest ADT. I had the identical issue and it was caused by a bug in the tools.

Second, clean the affected project and try again.

Comment: i have removed some jar files then it has resolved.thanks for ur suggestion

Answer (score 1):

I was getting this because I had manually added android.jar to the build libraries because it was saying it wasn't finding the android libraries. The fix was to...

1. Remove android.jar from the build libraries
2. Right click on the project, go to "Android Tools", and select "Fix Project Properties"

Hope this helps.