# How to solve "Conversion to Dalvik format failed with error 1" in android

Tags: android

I am getting `Conversion to Dalvik format failed with error 1` when I add `jaxrpc.jar` to my android project. But when I add `axis.jar` I dont get any issues. Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

1. First clean all jars;
2. Delete the project;
3. Reimport your project;
4. Make sure your SDK is right, and project select one SDK version;
   (This is my way to solve the problem) Right click on your project and select "build-path", next select "add Librarys", and add your private jars; do a clean-build and hopefully the problem is fixed;

see:

[Conversion to Dalvik format failed with error 1 with javax/net/SocketFactory.class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3284407/conversion-to-dalvik-format-failed-with-error-1-with-javax-net-socketfactory-cla)

Comment: I did this but when i add the javax.jar again i get the same issue. and i have to use that file