# Running Android project through Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, android-sdk-2.3

I have a problem running my android project through eclipse. It gives following error when I try to run it:

> trouble processing "javax/net/SocketFactory.class": ... Conversion to
>   Dalvik format failed with error 1

I am using Android 2.3.1 API level 9. The android.jar that is downloaded from AVD Manager has the javax/net package inside it.

I have searched on this issue and it seems to be the issue related to conversion of classes into Dalvik. But "javax/net/SocketFactory.class" is part of the android.jar. Any suggestions ?

Comment: have you seen this one?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3284407/conversion-to-dalvik-format-failed-with-error-1-with-javax-net-socketfactory-cla

Comment: yes i have used that one. Doing this also removes a third party library that i am using to process json. I have to add that library again so that it doesn't give compile time errors. Running after clean/build gives the same error.

Comment: The problem is resolved. I was mistakenly adding two android libraries at a time. One is added by default and other is added via Maven dependency. Removing the android dependency from pom.xml works. But now it is not working on terminal through mvn install command. This is a separate issue now.

Comment: Oops, did not notice that you solved the issue. Please feel free to ignore my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is resolved. I was mistakenly adding two android libraries at a time. One is added by default and other is added via Maven dependency. Removing the android dependency from pom.xml works. But now it is not working on terminal through mvn install command. This is a separate issue now.

Answer (score 0):

As you know android sdk comes complete with java sdk build in. This sdk is light weight and customized for use by the dalvik engine. Now, if we also add java jar’s along with the android app, obviously the android system will have trouble converting that java jar to dalvik. Hence the “conversion to dalvik” issue.

So now that you know what happens, lets figure out why it happens.

In my case it was the barcode, zxing framework that caused the problem. You have to find out what is causing the issue in your setup.