# Possible To Remove Android Dependencies?

Tags: android

I have an application that has been working and compiling just fine so far. However when I go to Export it, Android Dependancies is added automatically, which throws a

> Conversion to Dalvik format failed with error 1

I've put research into this and I know it is because Android Dependencies is adding duplicate files. I'm currently trying to clean that up, however is there a way to disable Android Dependancies from automatically being generated on export?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ended up just fixing the problem by removing the duplicated Jar files. Still wondering if this is possible, even if its not a good solution to the problem I ran into.

Answer (score 0):

Just clean your project via Project -> Clean.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I've tried that. A clean doesn't fix the duplicate file issue. I have to remove those files myself, but thats proving to be a bit of a challenge considering the complexity of the project

Answer (score 0):

Have you referred to these other similar questions?

1. ["Conversion to Dalvik format failed with error 1" on external JAR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2680827/conversion-to-dalvik-format-failed-with-error-1-on-external-jar)
2. [Conversion to Dalvik format failed with error 1 Solution?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6683955/conversion-to-dalvik-format-failed-with-error-1-solution)
3. [Conversion to Dalvik format failed with error 1 with javax/net/SocketFactory.class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3284407/conversion-to-dalvik-format-failed-with-error-1-with-javax-net-socketfactory-cla)
4. ["Conversion to Dalvik format failed with error 1" -- on export only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8161852/conversion-to-dalvik-format-failed-with-error-1-on-export-only)

Comment: Yeah I've gone through a ton of these on stack overflow so far. Nothing seems to be effective so far