# Android dependencies folder automatically created when eclipse restarts

Tags: android, eclipse

My project executes fine with out "Android Dependencies" folder in build path.

But when i restart/start eclipse, "Android Dependencies" is automatically added to project.

Do i need to change any setting in eclipse to stop this ?

Comment: @DjHacktorReborn any alternative to resolve this ?

Comment: mentioned all details in answer

Answer (score 0):

Android Dependencies is a virtual folder where Eclipse shows what JAR files the project depends on. It's not a physical folder; you won't find it on your hard disk. And the folder is not checked in into Subversion.

**Do not delete that folder. You will destroy your project.**

To fix it, just revert to an older Subversion revision and check it in again.
The dynamic classpath container called “Library Projects” has been renamed to “Android Dependencies” as it now contains more than just Library Projects.
http://tools.android.com/recent/dealingwithdependenciesinandroidprojects

Comment: in my case its not destroying the project. By the way, I deleted this due to duplicate libraries issue.

Comment: for other detail this link might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11532600/possible-to-remove-android-dependencies