# Android Signing application on Windows

Tags: android, publishing, keytool, jar-signing, jarsigner

I am trying to Sign up APK to upload it on to the Play Store Market. I am following the steps underlined [here](http://www.xploredj.com/signing-release-mode-android-app.html)

I am getting the following error

[image]

When i try to Sign the Application using Eclipse `project->Android Tools->Export Signed Application Package`.

[image]

Comment: write `C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_27\bin\my-relea
se-key.keystore` in `""`. like `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_27\bin\my-relea
se-key.keystore"`

Comment: Why not use Android Tools -> Export Signed Application Package? It does the same anyway. But a lot easier.

Comment: @SiddharthLele i did that i am getting an error. have updated the question.

Comment: @MMohsinNaeem i pulled the apk file into the same folder and now am getting a new error. have updated the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to do it with commands. In Eclipse, right click on your project->Android Tools->Export Signed Application Package.

Follow the wizard and you will have an signed apk without pain.

**Edit:**

After a quick search about the new error, [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3284407/conversion-to-dalvik-format-failed-with-error-1-with-javax-net-socketfactory-cla) seems to contain possible fix for you. At instance, please try to clean your project and build it again. If it does not fix your problem, also try the fix mentioned in the link.

Comment: i am getting an Dalvik error. have updated the question with a screenshot

Answer (score 1):

Copy your keystore file to a directory which has no spaces. Your current path is **C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_27\bin\my-release-key.keystore** which contains the directory **Program Files (x86)** with spaces. JarSigner cannot identify directories with spaces.

Comment: how can i do it in another director ? does copying just the jarsigner outside work ?

Comment: no just copy the .keystore file to another directory. eg. C:\Keystore\my-release-key.keystore

Comment: i put the keystore in the same folder i am getting the following error - jarsigner: unable to open jar file: Nomad.apk

Comment: is Nomad.apk in the directory where jarsigner is located? i.e C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_27\bin

Comment: am sorry i pasted the wrong error. i have updated the question with the screenshot i am not able copy paste it here

Comment: did you use the .apk file located in the bin folder of your project? Try exporting the apk by right clicking the project in the Package Explorer Adroid Tools > Export Unsigned Application Package

Comment: I did that as well. same problem when trying to jarsign it