# PhoneGap barcodeScanner plugin not exporting due to "conversion to dalvik format failed with error 1"

Tags: java, javascript, android, cordova

I'm using PhoneGap 2.7 and trying to install the BarcodeScanner plugin. I'm doing everything [by the book][1], and don't get any errors in the LogCat nor Console.
When I'm exporting it out to .apk I get this error:

> Conversion to dalvik format failed with error 1

Online reaserch shows that it might be something related to the barcode library's proguard file and conflicting classes. I am new to Android develpment and can't really figure out what cause this conflict. Help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, [that's it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3284407/conversion-to-dalvik-format-failed-with-error-1-with-javax-net-socketfactory-cla):

Go to Project » Properties » Java Build Path » Libraries
Remove all except the "Android X.Y" click OK.
Go to Project » Clean » Clean projects selected below » select your project and click OK.